# How can I solve this infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, simulation

I'm trying to make a game which is based on custom-made economic system. I tried to make the value of currency increased by someone earning it, as the currency is decreased as the one takes it.
And this is an example of the situation:

1. Let there is currency sized $50\text{T}$.
2. Let $A$ earns 10T by playing a game. Then there is currenty of left $40\text{T}$, and $10\text{T}$ becomes not able to earn by another player, because $A$ already took it. At this time, let $A$ did an effort sized $10\text{e}$. Namely, the value of $\text{T}$ is $1\text{e/T}$.
3. At this time, the currency left becomes $40\text{T}$, making the value of currency increasing.
4. Let $B$ did the same effort (amount of $10\text{e}$). $A$ earned $20\text{%}$ of the total amount of currency by the same effort with $B$, $B$ must earn the same cost that is corresponding to his effort.
5. At this time, left currency is $40\text{T}$, and $20\text{%}$ of that is $8\text{T}$, meaning that $B$ will earn $8\text{T}$ by doing the *effort*. Namely, the value of $\text{T}$ is $1.25 \text{e/T}$
6. And again, the currency becomes more worthy as left currency are lesser than before $B$ did his effort.

What the problem in this situation, is that these situations result different consequent:

- Doing *effort* of $10\text{e}$
- Doing effort of $5\text{e}$ and doing it again.
- Doing effort of $3\text{e}$, doing it extra twice times, and doing effort of $1\text{e}$

What I want to make is balance these situations to result in same consequent.

I tried to calculate how much the *effort*-maker will earn by creating the algebraical model, but I cannot make it be worked in my game, like in a program. These are the tries:

- Let $T\text{[T]}$ to be amount of currency that is able to be earned.
- Let $g\text{[e]}$ to be the absolute value of an effort.
- Let $a\text{[e]}$ to be the value of total $T$'s.
- Let $u\text{[e/T]}$ to be the unit value of the currency.
- Let $c\text{[T]}$ to be the cost of an effort of sized $g$.

What are in the brackets are units. Then,
**(TL;DR)**
\begin{equation}
c=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n c_k
\end{equation}
Where
\begin{align}
c_n&={\Delta g \over u(\Delta g, n)} \\
\Delta g&={g \over n} \\
u(\Delta g, n)&={a + \Delta g \over T_n} \\
T_n&=T-\sum_{k=1}^n c_k
\end{align}

I want to compute the general term of $c$ when $T,g,a$ is defined.
How can I do‽

P.s. I'm Korean so the translation may not be perfect. If somewhere is not understandable, please let me know by comment.

Comment: From the equations you have written, after some algebra $c_n=\frac{T-S_{n-1}}{2+an/g}$ Where $S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n c_k$. The $c_n$ must be determined recursively, and $c_1 = \frac{T}{2+a/g}$. Your expression for $c$ is then given by $S_\infty$. If it converges, then $S_\infty = T$, and you need $a/g>0$ for the sum to converge.